# Definir quantidade de resultados retornados por função que filtra JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, filtro

Tenho o seguinte código para filtrar um `JSON`, ele funciona perfeitamente, o único problema que estou tendo é para escolher o numero de resultados exibidos. (atualmente só exibe um único resultado).

```
var elemento = document.getElementById("galeria");
var SearchTag = function (jogo) {
        var i = 0;
        for (i = i; wallpapers.length > i; i += 1) {
            if (wallpapers[i].jogo === jogo) {
                return wallpapers[i];
            }
        }

        return null;
    };

    var wall = SearchTag('tag-para-filtrar');
    if (wall)
    {

    elemento.innerHTML +=
  "" + wall.id + "" +
  "" + wall.thumburl + "" +
  "" + wall.nome + "" +
  "" + wall.autor + "" +
  "" + wall.protecao + "" +
  "" + wall.tags + "" +
  "" + wall.jogo + "" ;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altera a tua função da seguinte forma:

```
var SearchTag = function (jogo) {
    var arr = arrary();
    for (var i = 0; wallpapers.length > i; i ++) {
        if (wallpapers[i].jogo === jogo) {
            arr.push(wallpapers[i]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
};
```

Agora o teu retorno será um Array de resultados, ou um array vazio. Trata da seguinte forma:

```
var wall = SearchTag('tag-para-filtrar');
for(var i = 0; i < wall.length; i++)
{

elemento.innerHTML +=
"" + wall[i].id + "" +
"" + wall[i].thumburl + "" +
"" + wall[i].nome + "" +
"" + wall[i].autor + "" +
"" + wall[i].protecao + "" +
"" + wall[i].tags + "" +
"" + wall[i].jogo + "" ;
}
```